# What are the benefits of using the Visual Studio publish feature in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, publishing

What are the benefits of using the Visual Studio publish feature in asp.net? Just because first request to the website take times? Or preventing Source code? (we can use classlibrary project  and publish the dll of that code) Is there any other benefit of Publishing?
Thank you .

Comment: Hmm... Don't see how this is "subjective and argumentative", unless the post is misread (imagine that). All Mostafa is asking is about the benefits of using the Visual Studio publish feature, which is *objectively* equivalent to compiling and uploading the required files. It has nothing to do with the benefits of the ASP.NET platform.

Comment: Yes  @jchapa , Maybe my poor English caused misunderstanding . My question was exactly "benefits of using the Visual Studio publish feature" .

Comment: Right. Did my answer assist you (see below)

Comment: Yes , Thank you . Because i supposed maybe there is another reason for publishing that i don't know

Comment: Maybe the people who closed this without any explanatory comment might now be good enough to re-open it? +1 to jchapa :-)

Comment: 'closure' nazis really bug me. some people clearly can't ask a straight question but if you gave this one more than 5 seconds you'd realise exactly what was being asked. some people just need to chill out a little :/

Comment: This isn't at all subjective and argumentative. OP is asking about the "Publish" feature in Visual Studio. 
Please re-open - this is a real and genuine question (unless you can find a duplicate).
And in future - please read the question and not just the title before voting to close - you've all done the SO community a disservice with this action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishing simply provides you with a quick way to put the needed files on the server. Like you said, you can just as easily FTP (or whatever method you're using) the files up to the server, protecting your source code by using the compiled assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

There is very little benefit to publishing in ASP.NET, it's a convenience more than anything else.

Publishing won't secure your code - you need to obfuscate for that, and even then there's no guarantee your code is secure.